# Datatable Jquery based plugin - table - issues with collapsible in table - Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, datatables

I need to create a web-based table of grants focused on access to care that can be filtered and sorted by results. Although I've never really worked much with Javascript (a little with HTML a long time ago), I've been able to complete most of my objective through the use of the Jquery DataTable plugin. I would like to provide our users with the option to hit a collapse button to review the abstract (which is oftentimes 1000 characters) if they want to find additional details.

I've been on Stackoverflow for a long time and I know it's expected to at least make an attempt, which I did. Sadly, I know I'm off.  I am grateful for any help here, since once I get this to work,  I'm done with this project!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
</script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Project Name</th>
      <th>Project Number</th>
      <th>PI(s)</th>
      <th>End Date</th>
      <th>Organization</th>
      <th>Abstract</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Geographic Access to VHA Rehabilitation Services for OEF/OIF Veterans</td>
      <td>DHI 06-010</td>
      <td>Diane Cowper, Ph.D </td>
      <td>9/30/2007</td>
      <td>VA</td>
      <td> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data- toggle="collapse" data-target="#example">Simple collapsible</button>
        <div id="demo" class="collapse">Abstract language example 2.</div>
      </
      </td>
    <tr>
      <td>Access to Specialty Dental Care - Racial Disparities</td>
      <td>R01-234i482</td>
      <td>John Summerton, MD</td>
      <td>1/1/2020</td>
      <td>AHRQ</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data- toggle="collapse" data-target="#example">Simple collapsible</button>
        <div id="demo" class="collapse">Abstract language example 1.</div>
      </
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a demo using `DataTable` [responsive](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) plugin

1. **[`control classes`](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/column-control/classes.html)**

   - `all` - Always display
   - `none` - Don't display as a column, but show in the child row
   - `never` - Never display
   - `control` - Used for the column responsive.details.type option.

   So, the last `th` in the header must have `class="none"`
2. **[`responsive.details.target`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/responsive.details.target)**

   This can be one of an column index, or a jQuery selector

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: {
      details: {
        type: 'column',
        target: '.collapse'
      }
    },
    columnDefs: [{
      orderable: false,
      targets: 5
    }],
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>


<table id="example" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="all">Project Name</th>
      <th class="all">Project Number</th>
      <th class="all">PI(s)</th>
      <th class="all">End Date</th>
      <th class="all">Organization</th>
      <th class="all">Abstract</th>
      <th class="none"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Geographic Access to VHA Rehabilitation Services for OEF/OIF Veterans</td>
      <td>DHI 06-010</td>
      <td>Diane Cowper, Ph.D </td>
      <td>9/30/2007</td>
      <td>VA</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example">Simple collapsible</button>
      </td>
      <td>Abstract language example 2.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Access to Specialty Dental Care - Racial Disparities</td>
      <td>R01-234i482</td>
      <td>John Summerton, MD</td>
      <td>1/1/2020</td>
      <td>AHRQ</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example">Simple collapsible</button>
      </td>
      <td>Abstract language example 1.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Great answer! However some details are missing. 1. For example, last `th` in the header must have `"class="none"` for this solution to work. 2. Visibility of the  column with additional details will be triggered by clicking anywhere in the last column, not just button. 3. All columns except last are forced to be visible with `class="all"` which may be undesirable on small screens.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com sorry for the poor explanation. Now I added some more words

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to `hide()` and `show()` elements using these functions or you can use `toggle()`

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').DataTable();
      $('#demo').toggle();
    });

    function myFunction(){
        $('#demo').toggle();
    }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
    </script>

    <body>
        
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Project Name</th>
          <th>Project Number</th>
          <th>PI(s)</th>
          <th>End Date</th>
          <th>Organization</th>
          <th>Abstract</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Geographic Access to VHA Rehabilitation Services for OEF/OIF Veterans</td>
          <td>DHI 06-010</td>
          <td>Diane Cowper, Ph.D </td>
          <td>9/30/2007</td>
          <td>VA</td>
          <td> 
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data- toggle="collapse" data-target="#example" onclick="myFunction()">Simple collapsible</button>
            <div id="demo" class="collapse" >Abstract language example 2.</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    </body>
```